# How can I require explicit return statements and forbid implicit returns?

Tags: rust

I want to ensure the code style is consistent by requiring this:

```rust
fn calc() -> u32 {
    return 1 + 1;
}
```

And forbidding this:

```rust
fn calc() -> u32 {
    1 + 1
}
```

Is there any setting in Cargo.toml?

Comment: This is like putting `#define begin {`, `#define end }` in your C files so you can make it look like ALGOL: it's a stupid trick that just makes your code look weird to anyone with actual experience. If you're interested in learning Rust, *learn Rust*, don't try to make it look like C or whatever other language you already know. It's not as if forbidding implicit `return` will magically make Rust into a statement-oriented language; you will still need to understand the underlying syntax. You're just making life harder for yourself (and for anyone else who has to read your code).

Comment: If you don't want an expression-oriented language, you should forbid this kind of statement: `let i = if condition { 0 } else { 1 };` and use `let i; if condition { i = 0; } else { i = 1; }`. Same for the `match`.

Comment: @trentcl It's probably already going to scare away majority of people who read the code, but when it doesn't... "***you must put return in your code***" if they ever try to contribute, definitely will.

Comment: @trent no, it's not like this, your example is completely unrelated. 
And this is from Clippy lint rule description:

"Why is this bad?
Actually omitting the return keyword is idiomatic Rust code. Programmers coming from other languages might prefer the expressiveness of return. It’s **possible to miss the last returning statement because the only difference is a missing ;**. Especially in bigger code with multiple return paths having a return keyword makes it easier to find the corresponding statements."

Answer (score 17):

I don't believe this can be done with Cargo itself, but [Clippy has a lint](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#implicit_return) for exactly this.

To enable the lint, place the line `#![deny(clippy::implicit_return)]` at the top of your root file (usually `main.rs` or `lib.rs`). Now running `cargo clippy` should show an error if you use implicit returns. You'll probably also want to disable the lint that has the opposite warning: `#![allow(clippy::needless_return)]`.

Example code:

```
#![deny(clippy::implicit_return)]
#![allow(clippy::needless_return)]

fn foo() -> u32 {
    0
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", foo());
}
```

And the error after running `cargo clippy`:

```
error: missing return statement
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     0
  |     ^ help: add `return` as shown: `return 0`
  |
note: lint level defined here
 --> src/main.rs:1:9
  |
1 | #![deny(clippy::implicit_return)]
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#implicit_return
```